# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' Using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, mysql-python

I´ve been programming a GUI with Tkinter to put the information necessary to connect into a database (MySQL), but i got this issue

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

This is how the GUI looks

[image]

This is the function of the button

```
def connect_bd():
    list = []

    user = txt_user.get()
    password = txt_pass.get()
    host = txt_host.get()
    port = int(txt_port.get())
    database = txt_database.get()

    list.append(user)
    list.append(password)
    list.append(host)
    list.append(port)
    list.append(txt_database)

    return list
```

And this is the rest

```
bdEntry = connect_bd()    

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
         user = bdEntry[0],
         password = bdEntry[1],
         host = bdEntry[2],
         port = bdEntry[3],
         database = bdEntry[4]
         )
```

Thre error is in the function:

```
  File "BuscarBD - copia.py", line 140, in <module>
    bdEntry = connect_bd()
  File "BuscarBD - copia.py", line 92, in connect_bd
    puerto = int(txt_port.get())
  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Do anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: The problem is simply that you're trying to convert an empty string to an integer. Often this is because you're calling the code before the user has had a chance to enter any data. Your error messages shows setting `puerto` but you've provided no code that does that. Please provide a [mcve] that shows how and when the code which causes the error is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write protective code around the port conversion to int

```
try:
    port = int(txt_port.get())
except ValueError:
    pass
    # Your logic goes here - what do you want to do if we dont have an int?
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, guess i will use PyQt5 as a GUI, but thanks for helping!

Comment: Not sure I understand what do you mean by "Still doesn't work".

Comment: Even with the `try except` it has other problem, and it is with the `tkinter.mainloop()`. When the mainloop() is at the end, i don't know why, the values of the function stays in 0

Answer (score 0):

I think that in line

> puerto = int( txt_puerto.get() )

The value txt_puerto.get() return is string with decimal value. For example :

```
>>> int('12.8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12.8'
```

what you need to do is to return

```
>>> int(float(12.8))
```

Comment: I guess that happens because, when the code runs, the tkinter.mainloop() puts that value like `('')` is an empty value. I actually don't know if that has something to be part of

Comment: @AlvaroNuñezMendoza You should try printing the output and figuring what's the part of code that's causing the error

Comment: According to the error message in the question, `txt_puerto.get()` is returning an empty string, not a float.